# Reverse whole date in php

Tags: php, date

OK,

i was using following code to reverse a date to use in php yesterday.

```
<?php
$d=date("F j Y");
$d=explode(" ", $d);
$month=$d[0];
$day=$d[1];
$year=$d[2];
<?php for ($i=10; $i>0; $i--)
{
      $date=$month."-".$day--."-".$year;
      echo $date;
?>
```

this was working for me till yesterday 31 March Night. but in the morning on april 1 its started printing

> April-1-2012
>
> April-0-2012
>
> April--1-2012   April--2-2012
>
> and so on.

this was the bad logic i used to reverse a date. i realized it soon. 
i want this like following.

> April-1-2012
>
> March-31-2012
>
> March-30-2012
>
> March-29-2012
>
> and so on

so how this could be possible ?

Thanks in advance.

---

Well, this also a logic that work perfect for me i made after post of question. but i am really thankful for all answers. that also making me many things clear.

```
<?php
$d=date("F j Y");
 for ($i=0; $i>-10; $i--)
 {
$date="<br>".date('F-j-Y', strtotime("+$i days"));
echo $date;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably the quickest way to do it

```
for($i=1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    echo date("F j Y", time()-($i*24*60*60)); //Instead of 24*60*60 write 86400 to increase slight performance
}
```

#### [Demo](http://ideone.com/FVw9L)

Answer (score 2):

To get an incremental decrease:

```
$date = date("F j Y");

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i)
{
  $dates[] = date("F-j-Y", strtotime($date . ' - ' . $i . ' day'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP5.2, you can use the DateTime Class and the modify method.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2006-12-12');
$date->modify('-1 day');
echo $date->format('F-j-Y');
?>
```

In 5.3, you can use the sub method in the DateTime class: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-20');
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
echo $date->format('F-j-Y');
?>
```

So an example, using the PHP 5.2 DateTime class (example here: http://ideone.com/uwkjj):

```
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('F-j-Y');
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    $date->modify('-1 day');
    echo $date->format('F-j-Y');
}
```

And here is an example using PHP5.3 DateTime class with the sub method

```
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('F-j-Y');
for($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++){
    $date->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    echo $date->format('F-j-Y');
}
```

There is also an interesting note on the PHP help page for strtotime: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php that says not to use it for mathematical operations. I wonder what that means. But I guess subtracting 1 day should be fine.

From PHP manual:

> Using this function for mathematical operations is not advisable. It
>   is better to use DateTime::add() and DateTime::sub() in PHP 5.3 and
>   later, or DateTime::modify() in PHP 5.2.